# Routing, matching a specific url if it contains a word

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

right now I have a map route that matches

```
foreach(var subcat in Sports.Categories)
{
routes.MapRoute("MultiRoute" + i, subcat+"/{title}", 
new { controller = "Routing", action = "Redirect", category = subcat });
}
```

I have some sports categories: Baseball, Soccer, Basketball etc.  but I also want to match Basketball with BasketBall-Plays, BasketBall-Highlights, Top-10-Basketball etc...

Which means I have to allow subcat to have a wildcard before and after, as BasketBall-Plays contains the word Basketball, I want it to redirect there.

How can I do a contains section for map routing?

**Edit: TLDR**: I have a subcat named basketball, but I want to match every url that has the word basketball in it. So Basketball-plays/top-10 should actually hit basketball/top-10

tried:

```
foreach(var subcat in Sports.Categories)
    {
    routes.MapRoute("MultiRoute" + i, subcat+"/{title}", 
    new { controller = "Routing", action = "Redirect", category = subcat }),
new{sub = ".*"+sub+".*" });
    }
```

Comment: One of the overloads is a constraint which accepts a regex.

Comment: @Silvermind I am aware of the constraints overload, but can I perform the regex on the subcat? I thought I could only use it for {title} parameters

Comment: After verifying it seems your routing is a bit of. Could you please show a few example URL's and what controller->action they must call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understood correctly, the following should work,

```
var subCategories = new[] { "Soccer", "BasketBall", "Golf" };
foreach (var subcat in subCategories)
{
    routes.MapRoute(subcat, "{subcat}/{title}",
                        new {controller = "Routing", action = "Redirect", category = subcat},
                        new { subcat = @".*\b" + subcat + @"\b.*" });
}
```

It will route

- Basketball/top-10
- Basketball-plays/top-10
- Basketball plays/top-10
- Top-10-Basketball/sometitle

hope this helps.